# Different behaviour in XP and Windows 7

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to do something dead simple...

I have two forms: `Main` and `Child`. 
On the `Child` form, there is a `TextBox1` (not empty). When the form closes, the following code runs:

```
Main.AnyObject.Value = TextBox1.Text
```

Back on the `Main` form, one would expect `AnyObject.Value` to contain the value of the `TextBox1`, right? True, but *only on Windows 7*. `AnyObject.Value` is *empty* on XP.

Any ideas why?

If it can be of any help, some technical specs:

- I use Visual Studio 2010 Pro both on a Windows 7 and an XP machine
- .NET Framework is 4.0
- `AnyObject` is declared as Public

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By *when the form closes* you mean which event? `Closing`, `Closed`, `Deactivated`?

Comment: Is AnyObject static? When do you run provided code, in the FormClosing event handler? What is the reported value of TextBox1.Text when that code is run, _is_ it empty?

Comment: May be missing something. but Child.textBox1.text. Otherwise I'm struggling to see what's plugged in where from what you have said

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar To close the form, the user has to press the button "Done". When the button is clicked, the data is saved and the form is closed with `Me.Close`

Comment: @CodeCaster AnyObject is static. And when in Debug Mode, before the Child form closes, I check the value of TextBox1, it is not empty.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I'm not sure to understand your comment. `AnyObject` is declared as a static object in the `Main` form. The `Child` form tries to assign it a value through `Main.AnyObject.Value = TextBox1.Text`